# How to add properties to an dynamically changeing object, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Consider this code. Where I load a string into an array. Then send the string to see if it changes, whether it does or not, add it. But since Im using a simple array to do this I cant add properties to the array elements.

```
....
var generationOffspring = [];
var offspringScore = 0;

// "load" the offspring into an array, check each offspring if it mutates and then score it.
for(var i = 0; i < amount_offspring; i++)
{
    // "load" text into array
    generationOffspring[i] = start_text;
    // send the string to see if it evolves
    generationOffspring[i] = evolve(generationOffspring[i], target_text);
    // then score the string
    offspringScore = score(target_text, generationOffspring[i]);
    ....
```

So how do I get this `offspringScore` to be assosiated with the `generationOffspring[i]` ?

Comment: Why not simply use an object in that case? An array with nested objects: `[{string:'', score: 0}]`? Or am I misunderstanding your issue?

Comment: @somethinghere Im quite new to object oriented programming. But I've looked into what you say `[{string:'', score: 0}]` my problem is really if `string` in this case is changeing. Does it still work? How do I initilize it if so?

Comment: I have a feeling your are overcomplicating this a bit. To understand your code, I need to know what `evolve` and `score` return. I also do not know where `target_text` is coming from. All I was saying is instead of having an array of strings, have an array of object that have a property representing the string and another representing the score related to this string.

Comment: @somethinghere evolve simply returns the string again, albeit it might have changed. Score returns an integer. You are explaining exactly what I would like to do. So I could initilize it like so `var generationObject = [{string:'', score: 0}]`. Then inside my loop to reach the diffrent properties. `generationObject.string = evolve(generationObject.string, target_text);` then `generationObject.score = score(target_text, generationObject.string`. Would this be correct?

Comment: Yes I think that should work!

Comment: Will try, thanks man!